# python regex match doesn't work. Attach an example

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex

my pattern is "trace_.*(a|bsel|cl|cs|d|ds|ls|sd|we_n|q)$ - it means: string should contain
trace_`<any_string>`<only a or only bsel or ,,,, or only we_n or only q>`END

my s is "dfd_printf_trace_data"

for example if s="dfd_printf_trace_data" then it should not match.
If s = "trace_printd" or trace_basel or trace_d then it should match

I write it but it doesn't work

```
import re s="dfd_printf_trace_data" 
pattern = r"trace_.*(a|bsel|cl|cs|d|ds|ls|sd|we_n|q)$" 
re.search(pattern, s)
```

It match but it should not match.

Any idea how to fix it ?

Thanks,
Alex

Comment: you have `a` as the last character in `data`. if this needs to be excluded, then need a rule for it. or add `_a` instead of `a` in acceptable group.

Comment: why shouldn't it match? trace_data matches perfectly

Comment: In "trace_printd" the `.*` matches "print". In "trace_data" the `.*` maches "dat". You will need more rules if you don't want a match here.

Comment: refer here,pls [regex playground](https://regex101.com/r/jFDMHm/1)

Comment: it doesn't work because it generates double '_'  . For example. trace__d matches instead of trace_d @simpleApp

Comment: You need a concrete rule to decide which testcase should match and which should not. Why should `d` be matched as a part of a word whereas `a` should not?

Answer (score 0):

re.search() searches for matches in substrings within the string.

You should use re.match() instead to check if the whole string matches your regex.

EDIT : misunderstood your question. You have a regex problem. I think the regex you are looking for is `trace_(a|bsel|cl|cs|d|ds|ls|sd|we_n|q){0,}$`. Check https://regex101.com/ to build regex from trial and errors.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this.

```
import re

s = "dfd_printf_trace_data"
pattern = r"^trace_d(a|bsel|cl|cs|d|ds|ls|sd|we_n|q)$"
match = re.search(pattern, s)

if match:
    print("Matched")
else:
    print("No matched.")
```

Comment: `(?!)` is not lookbehind, and this doesn't seem to be what OP is looking for.

Comment: Why did you add the beginning of string anchor, `^`?

Answer (score 0):

You are saying it should match *"trace_basel"*, yet, the letters you provide are *"bsel"*.

That might be the error.

```
trace_.*(a|basel|cl|cs|d|ds|ls|sd|we_n|q)$
```

Or, it *should* be *"bsel"*.  And, if that isn't matching, then you'll need to add the ^ character.

```
^trace_.*(a|bsel|cl|cs|d|ds|ls|sd|we_n|q)$
```

Additionally, if you don't require the capture, you can use the *?:* specifier.

```
trace_.*(?:a|bsel|cl|cs|d|ds|ls|sd|we_n|q)$
```

Answer (score -2):

I believe the dot has a special regex meaning.
Escape the ',' by doing '.' instead.